# return NOT exiting function properly in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I'm running a recursive function which searches a room for an object.  This code is working in conjunction with another process essentially running the same code.  The first thing the code does is check to see if the other one has found the object and, if so, it is supposed to break out of the function.
When I do the check to see if the other process has found the object, if it has, I use "return" to break out of that function at which time it's supposed to move onto other lines of code...However, for some reason it doesn't fully break out but instead just runs the function again and again.

Any ideas on how I can get it to break out?

I would and can provide the code but it's kind of long

**EDIT**

*Parent script*

```
!matlab -r "zz_Mock_ROB2_Find" & distT = 0.3; 
Rob1_ObjFound = 0; 
matrix = search_TEST_cam(rob, vid, 0.3, XYpos, 'north', stack, matrix, 0); 
disp('I"M OUT')
```

*Recursive code*

```
function matrix = search_TEST_cam(rob1, vid, distT, startingPos, currentDir, stack, matrix, bT) 
Rob1_ObjFound = 0; 
Rob2_ObjFound = 0; 
try 
    load('Rob2_ObjFound.mat', 'Rob2_ObjFound'); 
catch 
end 

if(Rob2_ObjFound == 1) 
    setDriveWheelsCreate(rob1, 0, 0); 
    disp('ROB_2 FOUND THE OBJECT') 
    pause(0.5) 
    BeepRoomba(rob1) 
    pause(0.5) 
    setDriveWheelsCreate(rob1, 0, 0); 
    return 
end
```

Comment: Where is the recursion in the above code?

Comment: I don't see it either. OP is not being very clear.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`break`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/break.html) to break out of a `for` or a `while` loop and terminate execution, i.e., statements after that are ignored. For e.g.,

```
for i=1:5
    if i==3
        break
    else
        fprintf('%u,',i)
    end
end
```

outputs `1,2,` and the code terminates when `i=3`. If you have nested loops, `break` will only break out of its current loop and move on to the parent loop.

To skip only the current iteration and move on to the next, use [`continue`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/continue.html). Using the same example,

```
for i=1:5
    if i==3
        continue
    else
        fprintf('%u,',i)
    end
end
```

outputs `1,2,4,5,`.

Using [`return`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/return.html) in a function just returns control to the parent function/script that called it.

It seems like you're using the wrong one in your code. However, it's hard to tell without knowing how you're using them. Anyway, you can try one of these three and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: I'm using 'return' in the function
the parent function looks like the following:
"!matlab -r "zz_Mock_ROB2_Find" &
distT = 0.3;
Rob1_ObjFound = 0;
matrix = search_TEST_cam(rob, vid, 0.3, XYpos, 'north', stack, matrix, 0);
disp('I"M OUT')"
the problem is that it never gets out of the search_TEST_cam code
that code...at least the beginning part looks like this:

Comment: "function matrix = search_TEST_cam(rob1, vid, distT, startingPos, currentDir, stack, matrix, bT)

Rob1_ObjFound = 0;
Rob2_ObjFound = 0;
try
    load('Rob2_ObjFound.mat', 'Rob2_ObjFound');
        
catch
end

if(Rob2_ObjFound == 1)
    setDriveWheelsCreate(rob1, 0, 0);
    disp('ROB_2 FOUND THE OBJECT')
    pause(0.5)
    BeepRoomba(rob1)
    pause(0.5)
    setDriveWheelsCreate(rob1, 0, 0);
    return
end
..
..
..
all the recursive code.."

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without seeing your code, but I doubt it's a problem with the [RETURN](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/return.html) statement. It's more likely a problem with how you've set up your recursion. If your recursive function has called itself a number of times, then when you finally invoke a RETURN statement it will return control from the current function on the stack to the calling function (i.e. a previous call to your recursive function). I'm guessing the calling function doesn't stop the recursion properly and ends up calling itself again, continuing the recursion.

My advice: check the exit conditions for your recursive function to make sure that, when the object is found and the most recent call returns, every previous call is properly informed that it should return as well.